# a sensible approach to highcharts x-axis labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

By default Highcharts staggers the x-axis labels over as many lines as are necessary in order to show them all, e.g.

[image]

which in this particular case, looks crazy. There is a [staggerLines option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.staggerLines), that can be used to specify how many lines to spread the labels over. If I set this to 1, I get something equally undesirable:

[image]

All the labels are stuffed onto the same line, such that none of them can actually be read. Is there some way that I can persuade Highcharts to show as many labels as possible on a single line, without them overlapping one another.

I realise  that there is a [step option](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.step) that can be used to show only every nth label, but this isn't much use to me, because the total number of data points (N) in the graph varies widely based on the user selection, so setting n is fairly meaningless when N is so variable.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) to define distance between ticks.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this using the [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) property and some very basic algebra. The number of labels shown on the graph is given by

```
seriesLength / tickInterval = labelCount
```

So if we can only fit 11 labels, set `labelCount` to 11 and rearrange the formula above to solve for `tickInterval`:

```
var tickInterval = seriesLength / 11
```

The `tickInterval` property must be an integer, so convert it before assigning it to the axes' `tickInterval` property:

```
$j('#container').highcharts({

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: Math.ceil(tickInterval)
    }

    // other Highcharts properties omitted
}
```

Comment: @jlbriggs it's 2 lines of code, I don't think I'm going to win any Turing awards for it

Comment: point being it's code that is likely redundant and unneeded, to fix a situation that looks like it was likely created by not letting the chart do its job in the first place...

Comment: @jlbriggs if you know a better/simpler way to solve the problem, please post an answer

Comment: might I suggest looking at the answer I posted yesterday before I added a comment...?  You appear to be using categories on the x axis, but your data is not categorical, it's a time series. That is what the datetime axis type is made for.  Using any axis type other than categorical will result in the chart spacing the axis labels out appropriately without you having to do anything at all.

Answer (score 3):

1) You can use rotation:

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
    rotation: -90,
    align: 'right'
  }
}
```

2) If rotation will not help - you can calculate step (if xaxis categorized). This code will calculate step on load, on add series and on zoom.

```
chart: {
      zoomType: 'x',
      events: {
        addSeries: function() {
          var c = this;
          setTimeout(function(){c.xAxis[0].setExtremes(c.xAxis[0].dataMin, c.xAxis[0].dataMax)}, 10);
        },
        load: function() {
          var c = this;
          setTimeout(function(){c.xAxis[0].setExtremes(c.xAxis[0].dataMin, c.xAxis[0].dataMax)}, 10);
        }
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
          events: {
            setExtremes: function (event) {
              if (Math.abs(this.options.labels.rotation) == 90) {
                var labelWidth = parseInt(this.options.labels.style.lineHeight) + 2;
                var plotAreaWidth = parseInt(this.chart.plotBox.width);
                var labelsCount = Math.floor(plotAreaWidth / labelWidth);
                if (event.max !== null && event.max !== undefined) {
                  var pointsCount = Math.round(event.max - event.min);
                } else {
                  var pointsCount = Math.round(this.dataMax - this.dataMin);
                }
                var step = Math.ceil(pointsCount / (labelsCount * (this.tickInterval == null ? 1 : this.tickInterval)));
                this.update({'labels': {'step': step}}, true);
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Any JS fiddle for this?

Comment: @roydon-d-souza Try to change lineHeight to see how it works http://jsfiddle.net/x8nzoh1v/1/

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a categorized x axis?

The problem should solve itself if you instead use a datetime x axis, and let the chart figure out the tickinterval for you.

Comment: In most cases we can't allow the chart to decide the tickInterval, so in those cases we might need a way to dynamically set the tickInterval . I haven't still figured out a good way to do it.

Comment: I would suggest starting a new question with your particular problem(s) if there isn't an answer here that suits your needs.